# Run ifconfig without sudo

Tags: linux, sudo, embedded, ifconfig, busybox

I have an embedded Linux running on a imx6 platform. This is a freescale embedded linux. The problem is that there is no sudo available for this linux, but I need to activate and deactivate the wlan0 device by a user. I tried to add the user to the group root without any success. I also tried to add the whole command to the /etc/busybox.conf file, but this had no effect either.

How can I run this command as user without having sudo?

```
user@touch:~$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Permission denied
```

Comment: Can you use `su`to become root?

Comment: Running ifconfig outside root permissions is a security risk. [Edit your sudoers file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line) so you are allowed to sudo ifconfig.

Comment: Why don't you make an answer of your comments?

Comment: @nlu The question is already answered for me. See answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If any non root user would be trusted to do so, you can merely add a setuid flag on ifconfig exec:

```
chmod 4755 /sbin/ifconfig
```

It will grant root privilege for execution of this executable to anyone. 
Of course, you need to have root access to run the chmod.

Comment: Doing this is a serious security risk. It opens up tampering with your network traffic, even to the users visiting you website. A reverse shell exploit willl then expose all network traffic to the attacker.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to use `sudo` to run the `ifconfig` command, just make sure that the `/sbin` is on your PATH .

as an unprivileged user run:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
ifconfig
```

Comment: this isn't related to what the OP asked. Running `/sbin/ifconfig` is exactly the same as running `ifconfig` with `/sbin` in the path

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Right , you will be able to read the ouput of the `ifconfig` command ; the `/sbin/ifconfig` will work but the write access will be denied e,g: `/sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down` will not work

Answer (score 1):

1. For new Linux users; the package `sudo` gives a non-priveleged user a preset number of minutes to do things to the system that only the System Administrator ('root' == 'uid=0') can do.
2. The program `ifconfig` has a lot of security issues associated with it for Linux operating systems that are on public facing servers. For desktop and home servers that have KVM connections, don't require SSH access and don't want 24/7 internet connectivity, this program has lower security requirements.
3. `ifconfig` is protected by another program called `netdevice`. This program provides low level access to Linux network devices. See `man netdevice`. The error that was thrown *SIOCSIFFLAGS: Permission denied* is because the program `ifconfig` is marked as privileged and requires an effective user ID of 0 ('root' <==> 'uid=0') or the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability. If this is not the case, `EPERM` will be returned.
4. In order to find out what `CAP_NET_ADMIN` is we have to read [capabilities(7) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html). The important info here is "CAP_NET_ADMIN: Perform various network-related operations such as interface configuration". In order to find out what `EPERM` is we have to read `man setuid`. The `EPERM` error is thrown when the user is not privileged (Linux: does not have the `CAP_SETUID` capability) AND uid does not match the real UID or saved set-user-ID of the calling process.
5. It is not possible to simply add your 'username' to the group 'root'. Example for Ubuntu distros: `sudo adduser username root` will not give you the necessary UID of 0 in order to pass all the security checks that `netdevice` demands. If `visudo` is available on the system one can see that the entry `Defaults secure_path=""` does not include a path to the program `netdevice.h`. So it is unlikely that modifying the sudo permissions (using `visudo`) for the `ifconfig` program will result in bypassing the security control provided by `netdevice`.

Assuming your not running a public server, the answer supplied by @tonioc is the easiest way to turn on and off the interfaces of a Linux distribution (such as Ubuntu that automatically enables all ethernet interfaces after a reboot) without using `sudo` privileges. The `sudo chmod 4755 /sbin/ifconfig` command is a simple way to modify your system such that a startup script such as `ifconfig eth0 down` can turn OFF an interface (without entering a password). For desktops/servers that have both intranet and internet networks attached (multi-NIC) it is critical for security that the internet networks remain OFF when they are not needed.